# Can I downgrade from Laravel 5.5 to 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I want to upgrade my application from 5.4 to 5.5, at first I was totaly fine with working 5.4 but now it seems like I can really make use of the new errors page. I've seen some other changes going on too and I wonder if I upgrade it from 5.4 to 5.5 and if something goes wrong, what options do I have. The project is saved in a private repository, I know I probably have a chance to go back to previous versions easly, but after doing development in 5.5, am I gonna be in a deadend for solutions?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to getter information before doing something. It's better to do that to dodge bullets isn't it?

Comment: your question title and body dont match.

Comment: Excuse my problem with communication than, I tried to explane myself the best way I can.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using `GIT` for `SVN`. Then just create a separate branch from master and upgrade and test it for a few days and if everything works fine then pull on production. Also, maintain a `5.4` branch for few days if you want to revert back. But it's very rare you will face any problem on `5.5` if you migrate correctly with through testing.

Comment: Did you do such upgrade yourself? And if you did, was there a problem that I need to reconsider before I upgrade

Comment: Laravel has a detailed documentation about upgrade process and they have mentioned every possible breaking change. So you can go through that. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade  Also if you are hesitating to do upgrade by yourself then you can use https://laravelshift.com/. They offer an upgrade at a low cost. I haven't used that service though.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge, I will try it and respond